# SQLite - How to Convert Money to Int then Insert into Table

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I'm having trouble changing a value, say $100,000 to an int (100000) and then inserting it into a table. All I have is something like:

```
 $sql = "insert into job (salary)"."values ($salary)"."where REPLACE(REPLACE($salary,'$',''), ',' , '');
```

As you can see I've no idea what I'm doing really. Maybe if there's an easy way of turning ints into money I could use that too but I'm trying to cover all my bases in case someone writes: 20000 as a salary, or $20,000.

All help is appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you do the replacement in PHP before substituting into the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `REPLACE` function in the `VALUES` clause. Also, you need to put the `$salary` string in quotes.

```
$sql = "insert into job (salary)
        values (REPLACE(REPLACE('$salary','$',''), ',' , ''))";
```

Or do the replacement in PHP before substituting:

```
$salary = str_replace(array('$', ','), array('', ''), $salary);
$sql = "insert into job (salary)
        values ($salary)";
```

Comment: You're amazing. Thank you! Gah, it seems so easy when you put it that way.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

Function Used for Data type conversion in SQLite:

```
$sql = "insert into job (salary)"."values (convert(int, $salary))";
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: `CONVERT` won't remove commas and dollar signs.

Comment: This way is even easier, thank you! Sorry I already picked accepted answer :(

Comment: Welcome @Julia and you can choose this as accepted answer now as well, if it solves your problem better. :)